# rails link_to posts to incorrect id - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want my User to be able to change a boolean on a `Share` that they own, but my attempt at implementation updates the wrong record.

When I go to the show page for an `Item` with `id:7`, my controller loads the associated `Share` objects by looking for `Share`s that have `item_id` set to 7. When I then click the `Hide` or `Show` buttons, my code updates the associated `Share`'s `active` attribute, and then redirects to that same `Item`.

But if I go to the show page for an `Item` with `id:3`, and click those same buttons, my code redirects to and updates the `active` attribute for the `Share` with `item_id:7`, instead of `item_id:3`. Can anyone give me an idea as to why this is happening?

My Share model:

```
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :item

 def activate
  self.active = true
  save
 end

 def deactivate
  self.active = false
  save
 end
end
```

My Item model:

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shares
 end
```

In my `ItemsController#show` action, I have this:

```
def show
 @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by(item_id: @item.id)
end
```

In my `SharesController`, I have this:

```
def activate
 @owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by(params[:item_id])
 @owned_share.activate
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to item_path(@owned_share.item) }
  format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @owned_share }
 end
end

def deactivate
 @owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by(params[:item_id])
 @owned_share.deactivate
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to item_path(@owned_share.item) }
  format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @owned_share }
 end
end
```

And in my Item show view, I have this:

```
<% if @owned_share.active == true %>
 <div class="eight wide column">
  <%= link_to "Hide", share_deactivate_path(@owned_share.item), class: "button wide-button functional-red-button", method: :post %>
 </div>
<% else %>
 <div class="eight wide column">
  <%= link_to "Show", share_activate_path(@owned_share.item), class: "button wide-button functional-mint-button", method: :post %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did you try adding explicitly the param key? `share_deactivate_path(@owned_share.item.id)` or `share_deactivate_path(item_id: @owned_share.item.id)`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma yeah, it doesn't work.

Comment: So just put a byebug before that line and see the params, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the param you're receiving isn't `item_id`, but `share_id`, that's why despite you modify your query adding the attribute which to look for, it doesn't give you the expected result.

Update the param which to use for getting user's share, like:

```
@owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by(item_id: params[:share_id])
```

Although in this case isn't clear why you're using share_id to look for an item_id, most probably you could update that part too.

As both actions share some specific functionality, you could make just one that just updates the active attribute "flipping" its value:

```
# model
def toggle_active
  update(active: !active)
end

# controller
def update_active_status
  @owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by(item_id: params[:share_id])
  @owned_share.toggle_active
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to item_path(@owned_share.item) }
    format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @owned_share }
  end
end
```

It gets the current user's shares active value and alternate it by using `!`. Notice that if they don't have a default value, a negation of nil returns true.

```
!true  # false
!false # true
!nil   # true
```

Note `@owned_share.active == true` can also be `@owned_share.active?` or `@owned_share.active`.

Comment: thank you! correction: i'm not trying to use `share_id` to look for an `item_id` - i want to look up all `shares` that have a matching `item_id`. in my `ItemsController#show` above, i'm initializing Share with `@owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by(item_id: @item.id)`. but for some reason this only works if i pass `:share_id` as a param to `item_id`, in `SharesController#deactivate`.

Answer (score 1):

Because this:

```
@owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by(params[:item_id])
```

should be:

```
@owned_share = current_user.shares.find_by_item_id(params[:item_id])
```

Comment: `find_by(item_id: params[:item_id])` the other way is almost deprecated.

Comment: note that find_by will return nil if no record is found.

Comment: This solution performs a SQL lookup that excludes `item_id` - which is exactly what I don't need to exclude: `Share Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "shares".* FROM "shares" WHERE "shares"."user_id" = $1 AND "shares"."item_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]`

Comment: Check that `IS NULL`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma yeah, I see it. I'm not understanding why it's null. If I perform a `user.shares.find_by(item_id: params[:item_id])` in console, the record exists.

Comment: So most probably is that the value isn't coming to your controller as you expect. Is that last example from the console, how're you handling the params?

Comment: Technically I'm doing `user.shares.find_by(item_id: 9)` in console

Comment: So you can't replicate the params, you don't know if they certainly take the needed id attribute. At least print the params before the `@owned_share` initialization.

Comment: @SebastianPalma When I `print params` before the `@owned_share` init, I see this in console: `{"_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"9H6xmrBHWABt8DNl0LT1J005l+iy6rScuqRSPG4xw1P/DF4S2AeGYRvWSPAVxU3jsc6ZR3NCY83fZt58D1gWaA==", "controller"=>"shares", "action"=>"deactivate", "share_id"=>"9"}`. The share_id is going through, but now I'm getting an error that says `undefined method 'deactivate' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: So you have a `share_id` and you're passing an `item_id`, one of those you should change.

Comment: I'm confused. What should I change? I want to perform lookups of `Share` using `item_id` and `user_id`. Here specifically, I want to deactivate the `Share` whose `item_id` matches the id of the Item it belongs to. I don't care what the share_id is.

Comment: So just do `current_user.shares.find_by(item_id: params[:share_id])`, although that param should be named item_id, maybe you could edit your routes after checking this work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167846/discussion-between-sabaeus-and-sebastian-palma).